# Using Stored Procedure to populate dropdown box using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I am using MS Entity Model to attach to my db, and everything has worked fine. But I have a stored proc that returns a list that has two columns (one int and one text column) and I am trying to bind to a dropdownbox. The examples seem to show returning a single column or returning a data type of one of the tables. But my stored proc returns the values from various tables. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MVC or Web forms?

Answer (score 0):

In EF v1 you can only map a stored proc to an entity type.

In EF v4 you can map a stored proc to an entity type or a complex type.

So the solution will vary depending on which version of EF you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC once u have list bind it to the view using `SelectList`

some thing like this

```
   <%: Html.DropDownListFor( c => c.Movie.LanguageId, 
new SelectList((IEnumerable)Model.LanguageList, "LanguageId", "Name", null))%>
```